# Extract Form Fields values from flattened/read-only PDF using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

We are trying to extract various values from a PDF document and we received a sample PDF document from our client.

The PDF is an electronic PDF document and no form fields are available in it; AcroFields yields zero results. Looks like the document is a flattened PDF document.

We are able to retrieve the texts using **LocationExtractionStrategy**, but we couldn't extract the Checkbox/RadioButton selected values.

Can someone provide sugession to **extract Checkbox/RadioButton values from flattened PDF document**?

Snapshot:

[image: Snapshot1]

Snapshot with area selected:

[image: Snapshot1_AreaSelected]

**Update#1:** I tried with solution recomended in post [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549977/reading-legacy-word-forms-checkboxes-converted-to-pdf?rq=1) **The C# version of the code(Converted from the reference link) that doesn't work for my document **

```
public class CheckBoxExtractionStrategy : IExtRenderListener
{
    public class Box
    {
        private bool selectedA = false;
        private bool selectedB = false;
        private LineSegment diagonalA;
        private LineSegment diagonalB;

        public Box(LineSegment diagonalA, LineSegment diagonalB)
        {
            this.diagonalA = diagonalA;
            this.diagonalB = diagonalB;
        }

        public LineSegment GetDiagnol()
        {
            return diagonalA;
        }

        public bool IsChecked()
        {
            return this.selectedA && this.selectedB;
        }

        public void SelectDiagonal(LineSegment diagonal)
        {
            if (ApproximatelyEquals(diagonal, diagonalA))
            {
                this.selectedA = true;
            }
            else if (ApproximatelyEquals(diagonal, diagonalB))
            {
                this.selectedB = true;
            }
        }

        private bool ApproximatelyEquals(LineSegment a, LineSegment b)
        {
            float permissiveness = a.GetLength() / 10.0f;

            if (ApproximatelyEquals(a.GetStartPoint(), b.GetStartPoint(), permissiveness) &&
               ApproximatelyEquals(a.GetEndPoint(), b.GetEndPoint(), permissiveness))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (ApproximatelyEquals(a.GetStartPoint(), b.GetEndPoint(), permissiveness) &&
               ApproximatelyEquals(a.GetEndPoint(), b.GetStartPoint(), permissiveness))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool ApproximatelyEquals(Vector a, Vector b, float permissiveness)
        {
            return a.Subtract(b).Length < permissiveness;
        }
    }

    Vector moveToVector = null;
    Vector lineToVector = null;
    Rectangle rectangle = null;

    public IEnumerable<Box> GetBoxes()
    {
        return boxes;
    }

    List<Box> boxes = new List<Box>();

    public void BeginTextBlock()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ClipPath(int rule)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void EndTextBlock()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ModifyPath(PathConstructionRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        float x , y, w, h = 0;

        switch (renderInfo.Operation)
        {
            case PathConstructionRenderInfo.RECT:
                x = renderInfo.SegmentData[0];
                y = renderInfo.SegmentData[1];
                w = renderInfo.SegmentData[2];
                h = renderInfo.SegmentData[3];

                rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, x + w, y + h);
                break;
            case PathConstructionRenderInfo.MOVETO:
                x = renderInfo.SegmentData[0];
                y = renderInfo.SegmentData[1];

                moveToVector = new Vector(x, y, 1);
                lineToVector = null;

                break;
            case PathConstructionRenderInfo.LINETO:

                if (moveToVector != null)
                {
                    x = renderInfo.SegmentData[0];
                    y = renderInfo.SegmentData[1];

                    lineToVector = new Vector(x, y, 1);
                }

                break;
            default:
                moveToVector = null;
                lineToVector = null;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Path RenderPath(PathPaintingRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        if (renderInfo.Operation != PathPaintingRenderInfo.NO_OP)
        {
            if(rectangle != null)
            {
                Vector a = new Vector(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom, 1).Cross(renderInfo.Ctm);
                Vector b = new Vector(rectangle.Right, rectangle.Bottom, 1).Cross(renderInfo.Ctm);
                Vector c = new Vector(rectangle.Right, rectangle.Top, 1).Cross(renderInfo.Ctm);
                Vector d = new Vector(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, 1).Cross(renderInfo.Ctm);

                boxes.Add(new Box(new LineSegment(a, c), new LineSegment(b, d)));
            }

            if(moveToVector != null && lineToVector != null)
            {
                if(boxes != null && boxes.Count > 0)
                {
                    Vector from = moveToVector.Cross(renderInfo.Ctm);
                    Vector to = lineToVector.Cross(renderInfo.Ctm);

                    boxes[0].SelectDiagonal(new LineSegment(from, to));
                }

            }
        }

        moveToVector = null;
        lineToVector = null;
        rectangle = null;

        return null;
    }

    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on how the checkboxes and radio buttons are drawn. Are they drawn using DingBats? Some other font? Or using vector graphics? Or using small bitmaps? Please share a sample PDF for analysis.

Comment: @mkl Can you sugest me how to find out the font type or vector graphics? For sure it was not bitmaps. I couldn't share the PDF document as it is confidential customer document.

Comment: First test: can you select that symbol like normal writing?

Comment: As @mlk said it is important to see if the file has been flattened or not.

Comment: @mkl, I wasn't able to select the Checkbox symbol, able to select the associated text.

Comment: Please refer to the attached snapshots for more details.

Comment: Ok, at first glance that seems to indicate vector graphics. Thus, you need anot extended render listener.  Then you have to recognise the check boxes from the line pieces the listener is signaled about. Difficult to explain without example...

Comment: @mkl, I refererred this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549977/reading-legacy-word-forms-checkboxes-converted-to-pdf?rq=1, it wasn't able to detect the checkbox. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: @mkl, Yes you're correct, Extended render listener wasn't able to defect the checkbox. I refererred this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549977/reading-legacy-word-forms-checkboxes-converted-to-pdf?rq=1

Comment: From the screenshots it is apparent that your checkboxes look different from those recognized by the code in the post you found. The extended render listener implementation you need has to be customized for the instructions with which your checkboxes are drawn. As I don't have your PDF to inspect, I cannot tell you how to do that.